# trying to show elements of a dictonary that's stored in django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

What i have is a django project that stores a dictionary in a json model.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    jsonM = JSONField()
```

The dictionary is just a bunch of numbers. known as my sortedList
I am accessing these numbers in my html by passing then as a context variable in my views.py

```
numbers_in_sortedList = MyModel.objects.all()
return render(
    request,
    "showdata.html",
    context={'numbers_in_sortedList':numbers_in_sortedList },
)
```

I am able to show the dictionary on my html via:

```
<li>
{% for number in numbers_in_sortedList %}
    {{item.jsonM}}
{% endfor %}
</li>
```

this works find and shows 1 bullet point, with all the values in a dictionary.
however how can i access each individual element in the dictionary individually?
I have tried nesting a for loop but it doesn't seem to work, stating that "myModel object is not iterable"

```
 <li>  
       {% for number in numbers_in_sortedList %}
        {% for item in number %}
         {{item.jsonM}}
        {% endfor %}
       {% endfor %}
</li>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add an example of the json structure? Add an example of the current output and the expected one.

Comment: The json structure is empty its just a blank dictonary as [ ]. The current output is a single html bulletpoint with the list inside .[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] and what I am trying to get is a bullet point for each element in the dictionary.